# Display image after button click in android

Tags: android

Presently I am trying to display images at runtime, but whenever android application is reading then automatically displaying the image by reading from activity_main.xml file.

I am trying to display my result image in same activity page.

activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/friendship" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc1"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void onSaveClick(){
        String res,fname,sname;
        TestRelation tr = new TestRelation();
        Validations validate = new Validations();
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        EditText firstname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        EditText secondname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.second_name);
        fname = firstname.getText().toString(); 
        sname = secondname.getText().toString();
            if(validate.validate(fname, sname).equals("")){
                res = tr.checkRelation(fname, sname);
                text.setText(res);
            }else{
                text.setText(validate.validate(fname, sname));
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.friendship);
            }
            //System.out.println("res value"+res);      

    }
```

In the above code the image is displaying before clicking on the submit button.
Please help me to display image in the same activity page after clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the visibility of the **ImageView** such that it isn't shown at first `either from java or from xml` and then inside button action click listener you can change its visibility.

**From XML**

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

This will make the ImageView invisible. (You may also use **gone** instead of **invisible**).

And inside the action listener of button use the following:

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `android:src="@drawable/friendship"` from `activity_main.xml`